# Deleting the last element in my linked list

Tags: python, nodes

I've created a list using only the Node class

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, init_data):
    self.data = init_data
    self.next = None

def get_data(self):
    return self.data

def get_next(self):
    return self.next

def set_data(self, new_data):
    self.data = new_data

def set_next(self, new_next):
    self.next = new_next

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)
```

I've intialized the list and the last Node is `None`.
I'm trying to delete this node but don't know how to?

Comment: if self.next == None  , then assign second last node next to None ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. If the last node shouldn't have a `next` attribute, then simply `del lastnode.next` will do. But as I said, not sure this is what you want.

Comment: Trying to get what you want: we can create a linked list using your `Node`: `llist = Node(0, Node(1, Node(2)))`, for example. Are you asking how to modify `llist` so it becomes `Node(0, Node(1))`? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

One good way to do this is to keep track of the previous node and the current node, and then when you reach the end of the list, set the next of the previous to None.

```
prev = None
cur = head
while cur.next is not None:
    prev = cur
    cur = cur.next
if prev: #in case the head is the tail
    prev.next = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want a `List` class to manage your nodes.

```
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self._nodes = None

    def push(self, node):
        node.set_next(self._nodes)
        self._nodes = node
        return self

    def pop(self):
        if self._nodes is None:
            return None

        temp = self._nodes
        self._nodes = temp.get_next()
        return temp

    def __len__(self):
        l = 0
        n = self._nodes
        while n is not None:
            n = n.get_next()
            l += 1
        return l

    def remove(self, node):
        n = self._nodes
        p = None
        while n is not None:
            if n is node:
                p.set_next(n.get_next())
                n.set_next(None)
                return True

            p = n
            n = n.get_next()

        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def del_from_end(self):
    if self.head is None:
        return "No node to delete"
    else:
        current = self.head

        while current.next.next is not None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = None
```

Add this method in your linked list class which would look like

```
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        if head == "" or head is None:
            self.head = None
        else:
            self.head = Node(head)
```