# Popping last node/item off a single linked list

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, list, loops, nodes

First, I did look at this:  [Deleting the last element in my linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329760/deleting-the-last-element-in-my-linked-list) (studied it and my code for over an hour) and I just cannot seem to "get" this.

I am trying to:

1. Remove - "pop" - the last item off my single linked list;
2. Return that removed item, and, finally;
3. Print out the "new" list without the removed item.

This is my code:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, value, nxt):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt

    def __repr__(self):
        nval = self.next and self.next.value or None
        return f"[{self.value}]"#":{repr(nval)}]"

class List(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.begin = None
        self.end = None

    def push(self, obj):

        node = Node(obj, None) 
        if self.begin == None:
            self.begin = node
            self.end = self.begin

        else:
            self.end.next = node
            self.end = node


     def pop(self):
        end = self.end
        start = self.begin
        while start.next is not None:
            start = start.next
            start.next = None
        return end.value

l = List()

l.push("a")
l.push("b")
l.push("c")
l.push("d")

print (l)

print (l.pop())

print ("AND FINALLY:", l)
```

When I run this, I get:

abcd

d

AND FINALLY: ab

Of course I see that I am not iterating through the nodes far enough to get the the "c" node.  I have played around with the loop for a long time and cannot resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the condition and equally importantly the indentation wrong. You are also not updating `self.end` or testing if there is only 1 item in the list, e.g.:

```
def pop(self):
    end = self.end
    start = self.begin
    if start == end:
        self.begin = self.end = None
        return end.value

    while start.next is not end:
        start = start.next
    start.next = None
    self.end = start
    return end.value
```

Note: This doesn't address if there are no values in the list.

Also note: without a `__repr__()` or `__str__()` in the `List` class you would not get your expected output.

Comment: Got it.  This works, thanks.  I still don't fully grasp it but I think it is because I have been staring at this for far too long.  Thanks.

Also, thanks for the other input but FYI I do have a __str__ and some other functions but they are all working correctly so I did not want to crowd the question.

Comment: Also, if you would indulge a "follow up" question - what is the purpose of the second-to-last line you added: "self.end = start" - I didn't see a purpose for it so I "commented it out" (#) as a way to test it's functionality.  Nothing in the output changed.  Don't mean to be insulting, I am sure you have it there for a reason, but I don't get it.

Comment: Try popping off 2 values, second pop will fail because you haven't updated `self.end`. `self.end` is meant to represent the end of your list, but you've popped off your end, so what is the new end of the list.